# Add Datasheets as PDF in Latex

Tags: graphics, formatting, ieee-style

I am currently using an IEEE format for my document and I want to add datasheets on my appendix part. I have already linked the PDF within my LaTeX document using this code:

```
        \newcounter{ct}
            \forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 10}
            {
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,page=\value{ct}]{FILE.pdf}
            }
```

The problem is that the PDF I linked still adapts to the IEEE format meaning the datasheets follow the 2 columns of the IEEE format. Is there a way to link a PDF in my TeX document without following the IEEE format?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

The IEEE classes provide commands `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` to switch between single and double column format. So something like the following should work:

```
\clearpage
\onecolumn
... % include your pdf files here
```